# How to get file preview pane in Ubuntu 12.04 and nautilus

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, previews, nautilus-extensions, gloobus-preview

It seems like the default file manager in Ubuntu 12.04 is nautilus, that does not have a file preview option! This is a really important requirement for me and I am missing the good old file preview pane in Windows 7 or Mac OS X.

There are a few options in Ubuntu for instance; `gloobus-preview` but then it is activated when we press the <kbd>space-bar</kbd> and the preview occupies the center of the screen, so it almost blocks the view. Now, is there any way I can install an add-on, maybe to the nautilus manager in Ubuntu 12.04 and get this side-pane for previewing files.

- What are the other options available otherwise?

Comment: While this might not answer your question per se, Dolphin, KDE's file manager, does offer the functionality your searching for. In addition, I find it to be several times faster than Nautilus in most regards.

Comment: Thanks @MHC for your response, but could you give me a more elaborate solution on how to exactly go about using the dolphin file manager in ubuntu 12.04? thanks

Comment: You can install dolphin from the USC or via the CLI (sudo apt-get install dolphin). What's more diffucult, of course, is setting it up as the default file manager. There are a [bunch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168752/how-to-run-dolphin-instead-of-nautilus) of [Q&As](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84929/how-to-set-up-dolphin-as-default-file-manager) that dive into that topic. I myself am using a completely different desktop environment (LXDE), so I won't be of too much help.