# Nautilus stops working

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, dolphin

I have done a silly things. Some days ago I install dolphin in my Ubuntu 12.04. After that I was in love with dolphin for having thumbnail preview of folder with images inside. So, I thought of setting dolphin as a default file manager. So from the following link I found a solution:
[How to run Dolphin instead of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168752/how-to-run-dolphin-instead-of-nautilus)

I have not followed the whole artical. Just used the first code:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/dolphin /usr/bin/nautilus
```

It makes my default file manager as dolphin. When I click to home folder launcher it now opens with dolphin.

Now I want to revert to Nautilus. But I am not getting any way to go back. But I thought if I change the upper code it may revert. So, I changed it with:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/dolphin
```

And after that nautilus is not working. If I click home folder it also not working. If I write gksu nautilus in terminal it also not working after giving password. The only way  that is left to access file manager is using dolphin. So, please help me. I need a solution. I need to make everything like before.

Now when I try to access mounted drive from launcher. It says:

```
Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop" (Permission denied).
```

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you did - each piece of code explained:

> sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back

You renamed the Nautilus program to "natilus.back". (You misspelled too unless you meant to call it natilus instead of nautilus.)

> &&

If that succeeded (which it did)...

> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/dolphin

Make a link called nautilus which will actually execute dolphin every time nautilus is called.

--

By executing this...

> sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/dolphin

... I think you renamed your link over your backed up program - nautilus (now the link) over natilus.backup. So now the nautilus program is gone. (I will stand corrected as I am not totally sure about that.)

--

What you should have done to reverse this was remove the link...

> sudo rm /usr/bin/nautilus

...and rename the backup you made to its original name.

> sudo mv/usr/bin/natilus.back /usr/bin/nautilus

(Again, assuming you did actually name the backup natilus.back instead of nautilus.back)

--

To fix, still remove the link you no longer need...

> sudo rm /usr/bin/nautilus

...then remove and reinstall nautilus with apt-get.

> sudo apt-get remove nautilus && sudo apt-get install nautilus

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alhamdulillah. Your answer solved my issue. Many many thanks to you Jack. Please pray for me so that I can understand this kind of command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to revert back the changes, ok. Then just do:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
```

Is impossible to revert the commands since you made two big mistakes, instead of following the answers you followed the question. Also you ran `sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back` twice. The second one was totally unnecessary. If you wanted to revert it the correct command for both was:

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/nautilus && sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus.back /usr/bin/nautilus
```

Comment: Braiam, thanks a lot to you too. But as the first answer of Jack solved the problem, I have not tried yours one, but you guys are awesome, ubuntu community is too. Please keep up your support to the community. Please pray for me so that I can also understand linux, and be a power user of it.

Comment: Braiam's answers is more to the point.

Comment: @braiam,Just yesterday I have opened the askubuntu account, and this one is my first post in it, so I thought the first one above the list is the earlier one... lol to me. But thanks for answering first.

Comment: @Jack Yes, but you have figured it out that I am a novice.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for remembering. I have ticked right to the anwser of Jack.