# Dolphin Remote/network and Recently Saved places not working

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, dolphin, nas

I'm looking at the Dolphin file manager that comes with 18.04. I was encouraged to see the Recently Saved place, since I use the same files over and over. But nothing appears under Today or Network. I can see my NAS with Nautilus.

I've opened and saved a couple of files today after installing Dolphin.

I've added an entry under Network and entered the information I see in Nautilus (afp://admin@....)

What else can I do?

Comment: Among the official 18.04 flavors supported here, Dolphin is present only in Kubuntu. If you install Dolphin in other flavors, some features may or may not work, possibly because supporting software may not be present or may not be running during a GNOME session.

Comment: You maybe interested in the responses here: https://askubuntu.com/q/168752/248158

Comment: Okay, I installed Dolphin on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 VM. After running `balooctl enable` and letting the indexing complete, I could see an entry in *Recently Saved > Today*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MceJk.png. I don't know anything about Viewing Network files. • In Dolphin's  "normal" environment, KDE Plasma, the indexing daemon, baloo, doesn't need to be started manually. • Many KDE Plasma users turn off baloo because they have had bad experiences with it. I use it on my Kubuntu 18.04. • Baloo doesn't index everything: contents of dot folders and certain other stuff is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for working on this. This morning I submitted 'balooctl enable'. Response was: "Enabling the File Indexer" then "Failed to register via dbus. Another instance is running." I didn't execute another instance, to my knowledge. Because of your "letting the indexing complete", I let it sit while I did other things. For a few hours. I just control-C'd out of it. Looks like I'm just out of luck.