# KDE - Dolphin: Open folder in new window instead of new tab

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

After upgrade from Kubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 Dolphin opens new folders in a tab instead of a new window.

How to completely disable tabs in Dolphin?
How to open folders (e.g. by click from desktop) in a new window instead of a new tab?

Thanks and sorry for my czenglish :)

Comment: Maybe check/uncheck *Configure Dolphin > Startup > Open new folders in tabs*?

Comment: :D Thank you!  I don't understand why I didn't see it :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can go ahead and post that as the answer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) gave the correct answer in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232793/kde-dolphin-open-tab-in-new-window-instead-of-new-tab#comment2075191_1232793), but no one has created an answer so far, which is why this question cannot be marked as answered. So I'll just do it.*

If you want folders open in new windows instead of tabs (for example, when you open a folder from a terminal or other application) you can configure this in Dolphin preferences by unchecking `Configure Dolphin > Startup > Open new folders in tabs` option.

This won't disable tabs in Dolphin completely (in fact, I don't believe it's possible at all), so you can still open a new tab using an option in the menu or the `New Tab` button.

Answer (score 5):

You can go under File Associations and set your favorite application for folder, when choosing Dolphin, you can go in Application properties and add the command line parameter `--new-window` before the `%u`

thinking about this, you could have both configure, and have the option to right click -> open with -> dolphin new tab/window

see attached screenshot

[image: file associations settings]

Comment: Per comment by DK Bose - "Maybe check/uncheck Configure Dolphin > Startup > Open new folders in tabs? " - this worked for me.  Did not need to change the application properties.  Dolphin has configuration for this option.